# Clip in ConstraintLayout in Jetpack Compose not working

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make corners of ConstraintLayout rounded without using CardView. My current code is this but not working

```
ConstraintLayout(
    modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(100.dp))
        )
{...}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is working guys, I just added background after clip() and it's working fine.